# uploading image to mongodb using multer

Tags: typescript, next.js

Im trying to upload an image file to mongodb using multer and im getting this error in the terminal : **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')**
and **net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)** in the console

here is my code:

**api/upload/route.ts**

```
export const POST = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await connectToDB();
    console.log(req.file);
    upload.single("file")(req, res, async function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to upload file." });
      }
      const { filename, mimetype, size } = req.file;
      try {
        const file = new FileModel({
          filename,
          contentType: mimetype,
          size,
        });
        await file.save();
        res.status(200).json({ success: true });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to save file information.' });
      }
     
    });
  } catch (error) {
    new Response("Failed to upload", { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

**my multer.upload function :**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, Date.now() + ext);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg") {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      console.log("only png and jpg allowed");
      callback(null, false);
    }
  },
  limits: {
    fileSize: 2048 * 2048 * 2,
  },
});
```

**and here is my handleUpload where i do the fetch :**

```
const handleUpload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData));
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        body: formData,
      });
      if (res.ok) {
        router.push("/projects");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```